# Sending MSMessage in iOS 17 Simulator Fails

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, imessage, xcode15, msmessage

Using iOS 17 I notice when I compose an `MSMessage` and insert it into the active conversation and send it in the simulator the message does not appear in the the message thread.

The `didStartSending(_ message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation)` function is called when the message is sent, but there are no errors.

I'm expecting there is an error with iOS 17 Simulator and sending messages. Also, being able to debug sending a message and going to the receiver to open the message still crashes

Has anyone else experienced these issues or has any solutions?

I expected to have the ability to debug an iMessage app by sending a message, seeing it in the conversation thread, and going to the receiver to see the received message.